# Java: Unexpected concurrency in a single threaded ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, concurrency, runnable, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I have a number of `MyRunnable` objects scheduled on an `ExecutorService` created by `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)`. Each `stepX` method logs when it starts executing and according to my log I have `MyRunnable` objects with overlapping runtimes. I also have runtime errors which are consistent with two `MyRunnable` objects executing concurrently, so this likely isn't just the clock being wonky.

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        step1();
        step2();
        step3();
        step4();
        step5();
    }
}
```

I have no calls to `ThreadPoolExecutor#setMaximumPoolSize` in my code.

As far as I can tell, either my `Runnable`s are being preempted, or my 
`ThreadPoolExecutor` is growing beyond its `maximumPoolSize`. I expected both of those things to be impossible.

Comment: Try out `newSingleThreadExecutor()`—the doc says that "Tasks are guaranteed to execute sequentially".

Comment: How about showing some relevant code. Who knows that you aren't using multiple pools (something a lot more likely than a serious bug like that in `newFixedThreadPool`)?